# The bean is injected to constructor arg before properties are set

Tags: java, spring

I have the following bean configuration

```
<bean id="firstBean" class="...">
   <property name="someProperty" fef="someOtherBean"/>
</bean>

<bean id="secondBean" class="...">
   <constructor-arg ref="firstBean"/>
</bean>
```

The problem is that second bean tries to get someProperty from firstBean in the constructor, but it is not yet injected. Both classes are from library that I cannot change. Is there a way that I can enforce setting properties on firstBean before it is injected to secondBean?

Thanks

**EDIT**

The issue had no direct solution, so I solved it with factory that internally manages both beans and provides instanse of secondBean

Comment: How many arguments does `secondBean` constructor has?

Comment: One argument, no issue with that

Answer (score 2):

Make 2nd bean dependent on the 1st.

```
<bean id="secondBean" class=".." depends-on="firstBean">
```

This way spring will make sure `firstBean` is ready before instantiating `secondBean`.

Another option is to use a `FactoryBean` or a programmatic bean definition using `@Bean`. That way you have better control over the instantiation process.

Comment: I have tried it, it makes sure that object is constructed so that some statics for example are initialized, but it does not eforce properties being set

Comment: I'm sure it waits for the whole bean to get initialized. Or maybe I don't understand your case completely.

Comment: I have just tried it. In secondBean constructor the property is null. It was never set, I have checked in debugger

Comment: and are you sure the property has a value? What is it exactly? A ${property}, another bean, a hardcoded string?

Comment: Another bean that is defined in the same XML

Comment: So then you shouldn't be using `value` attribute if it is a bean. You should be using: `<property name="someProperty" ref="someValue"/>`

Comment: I do, this is just an example. I will go and change it to avoid confusion

Comment: And are you sure then that your other bean is not null when it is created? It should get created this way. Spring configuration seems to be correct.

Comment: That other bean is declared as regular spring bean, not via factory, how it can become null?

Comment: It is not invoked, this is the point. Spring instantiates firstBean, the instantiates secondBean injecting the firstBean, then it would call setters. However it doesn't get to last step, becaus of the NPE in secondBean constructor

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a look to `InitializingBean`. Take a look to the [doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html).

> Interface to be implemented by beans that need to react once all their properties have been set by a BeanFactory: for example, to perform custom initialization, or merely to check that all mandatory properties have been set.
>
> An alternative to implementing InitializingBean is specifying a custom init-method, for example in an XML bean definition. For a list of all bean lifecycle methods, see the BeanFactory javadocs.

Comment: neither of his beans are under his control, so he can't use that, I think

Comment: How do I apply it to library classes that I cannot change?